# Visual Studio adding custom breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I'am writing a custom debug engine which allows debugging some kind of workflow defined as xml.

Who is responsible for telling Visual Studio where a breakpoint can be set in a text editor?
I can set a breakpoint inside of the xml editor but only on xml elements.
Is there a way to tell Visual Studio also to add breakpoints somewhere between the start and end tag of an xml element?
So is it possible to add a breakpoint at line 7?

[image: Breakpoint]

Is this logic customizable or does it depend on the used text editor?

Comment: I didn't find a way to add a breakpoint for it. But I just test an HTML file with script, I found that it would be related to the text editor you use in your side. For example, we could add a breakpoint to the specific line if we use the default HTML Editor, but if I open it using the XML, it would add a breakpoint for the whole script as yours. So my understanding is that it would be related to the text editor.